# .htaccess dynamic grant access (include system-wide file)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a server hosting several domains and their subdomains and I'm trying to find the right way to protect some sensitive folders and subdomains using .htaccess. All good for now, but I have in mind a pretty doable solution (programming-wise) but I can't seem to get .htaccess to do my evil biddings.

Long story short:

- I have a list of IPs stored in a file/database
- based on this list I generate a file, let's say `/home/ip.allow`
- the file contains `Allow` entries ( `Allow from 123.123.123.123` )

In the domains/subdomains I host on this server I have simple .htaccess files with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
```

The thing I'm interested in is how do I include that `/home/ip.allow` so I don't have to programmatically find and edit all the .htaccess files in the vhosts path (having all the conditions in only one file would make my life so much easier).

I did find the `RewriteMap` directive in the [Apache's mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) but that seems to apply only for rewrites, not for granting access.

Any ideas on this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar using mod_rewrite. But you'll need to change a few things around.

Instead of having a file with a ton of entries that look like this: `Allow from 123.123.123.123` you'll need to create a key/value map so we can pass it to [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). In this example, since you are listing a set of IPs that you will allow access to, the file will have a bunch of entries that look like this: `123.123.123.123   allow`, where "123.123.123.123" is the key and "allow" is the value.

Now we have to setup a map for this by using `RewriteMap`, however, the catch is we can only use it in the server config or a virtual host config, and NOT inside a `Directory`, `Files`, or the .htaccess file. So you set this up somewhere in your httpd.conf or your virtual host file:

```
RewriteMap access_list txt:/home/ip.allow
```

Now you can access the map `access_list` in any .htaccess file by using a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) that accesses this map and a `RewriteRule` that does nothing except issue a `[F]` (Forbidden):

```
RewriteCond ${access_list:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} =""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` here just tries to find the `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` as a key to the map file. If the only thing in your map file is `123.123.123.123   allow` and the remote address is `127.0.0.1`, nothing will match and the map will return an empty string, thus fulfilling the `=""` bit. Otherwise if the remote address is `123.123.123.123` then "allow" will be returned and the condition will fail, thus granting access.

You can play around with granting or denying depending on how you've setup the map file.